# Inserting the URL of PDF (PDFKit) into database with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdf, url, pdfkit

I'm generating a PDF using the PDFKit library and I would like to insert the generated PDF into a MySQL database. On the client side, a user should be able to see the list of PDFs and choose one of these PDFs to download.

There might be similar question, but I've searched everywhere and nothing worked. I tried to put the generated file into a blob just like it is shown in the PDFKit documentation, but after a bit of research, I found out that it is directly put into a stream (I also tried buffers but it didn't work). I tried the get-stream but same problem

How to insert the generated PDF in the form of a URL that the users are allowed to view?

```
const PDFDocument = require('../util/pdfkit-tables');
const request = require("request");
const blobStream = require('blob-stream');
const getStream = require('get-stream');
const doc = new PDFDocument();
const fs = require('fs');

exports.postExam = (req,res,next) => { 

          var stream = request({
          method: 'PUT',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/medecin/makePDFexam/'
    

          doc.pipe(stream);
           /*Content pdf*/
          doc.end();


            db.query("INSERT INTO medicalexam SET Iduser =?, Idpatient = ?, date_medicalexam = ?, medical_exam =? ", [id_medecin, id_patient, db_date,stream,stream],
            (err, result) => {
              if(err) {
                console.log("error", err);
              }else{
                console.log("Medical Exam inserted");
              }
            });  
                      
  
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to store the pdf as a [static file](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) in your server's file system and then present a URL to your users allowing them to view it. Is that correct? Please [edit] your question or ask another.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you for your comment, I editted my question !